# Alguém poderia me ajudar a enxergar onde estou errado na minha alocação de fila

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _fila {
   int ini;
   int fim;
   int tam;
   int *vetor;
} Fila;

Fila* criar_fila (int tamanho) {
   Fila* fila = (Fila *) malloc (tamanho*sizeof(int));
   fila->ini = 0;
   fila->fim = 0;
   fila->tam = tamanho;
   fila->vetor[fila->tam];
   
   return fila;
}

void destruir_fila (Fila *f) {
   free(f->vetor);
   free(f);
}

void enqueue (Fila *f, int elemento) {
    if (f->fim < f->tam){
        f->vetor[f->fim] = elemento;
        f->fim++;
    }
}

int dequeue (Fila *f) {
   int elemento = f->vetor[f->ini];
   f->ini++;
   return elemento;
}       

int main () {

   /*Inicializando a estrutura de dados fila!*/  
   Fila *fila = criar_fila (10);

   /*Tentando inserir o elemento 1 na fila!*/ 
   int elem = 1; 
   enqueue (fila, elem);

   /*Tentando inserir o elemento 2 na fila!*/ 
   elem = 2; 
   enqueue (fila, elem);

   /*Tentando inserir o elemento 3 na fila!*/ 
   elem = 3; 
   enqueue (fila, elem);

   /*Tentando inserir o elemento 4 na fila!*/ 
   elem = 4; 
   enqueue (fila, elem);

   /*Tentando retirar e imprimir o elemento 1 na fila!*/ 
   printf("%d\n", dequeue (fila));

   /*Tentando retirar e imprimir o elemento 2 na fila!*/ 
   printf("%d\n", dequeue (fila));

   destruir_fila (fila);

   return 0;
}
```

Estou retornando fila, no método criar_fila(int tamanho) , porém está compilando mas da Segmentation fault.

Comment: Na função `criar_fila` você faz `fila->vetor[fila->tam]`, mas o que isso deveria fazer? Se o vetor é também um ponteiro, não deveria alocar a memória dele também?

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre em dois lugares, dentro da sua função `criar_fila`.

O primeiro é o fato de estar fazendo a alocação de memória suficiente para uma certa quantidade de `int`s, mas não para a sua estrutura `Fila`:

```
Fila* fila = (Fila *) malloc (tamanho*sizeof(int));
```

Sendo que o correto seria:

```
Fila* fila = (Fila *) malloc (sizeof(Fila));
```

Veja que removi a variável `tamanho` também da alocação de memória da sua estrutura `Fila`. Como está usando apenas uma estrutura com um vetor dentro **não precisa alocar memória suficiente para 10 (dez) estruturas, apenas uma**.

O segundo problema ocorre no uso do seu vetor a partir de um ponteiro. Veja que na função `destruir_fila` você tenta chamar `free` no seu vetor; mas em nenhum momento `malloc` foi chamado para alocar memória e permitir que seu ponteiro tenha para onde apontar:

```
Fila* criar_fila (int tamanho) {
   Fila* fila = (Fila *) malloc (sizeof(Fila));
   fila->ini = 0;
   fila->fim = 0;
   fila->tam = tamanho;
   fila->vetor[fila->tam];
   
   return fila;
}
```

Nesse caso, você pode inicializar seu ponteiro com o `malloc` e o tamanho que o vetor terá:

```
Fila* criar_fila (int tamanho) {
   Fila* fila = (Fila *) malloc (sizeof(Fila));
   fila->ini = 0;
   fila->fim = 0;
   fila->tam = tamanho;
   fila->vetor = malloc (tamanho * sizeof(int));
   
   return fila;
}
```

O resultado da execução do código agora é:

```
1
2
```

Comment: "não precisa alocar memória suficiente para 10 (dez) estruturas, apenas uma" técnica também conhecida como Rest Assurance Memory Allocation Pattern (https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Rest_Assurance_Memory_Allocation_Pattern)